# Como detectar um clique ou outro evento de mouse na NotifyIcon do win32gui?

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi

Estou tentando modificar a biblioteca [`win10toast`](https://github.com/jithurjacob/Windows-10-Toast-Notifications) para que eu possa passar um callback que seja executado quando o usuário clica na notificação do Windows 10 que mostro.

A "carne" da biblioteca, que condensei o máximo que pude pra criar um exemplo mínimo e funcional, está aqui:

```
from win32api import GetModuleHandle
from win32api import PostQuitMessage
from win32con import CW_USEDEFAULT
from win32con import WM_DESTROY
from win32con import WM_USER
from win32con import WS_OVERLAPPED
from win32con import WS_SYSMENU
from win32gui import CreateWindow
from win32gui import DestroyWindow
from win32gui import NIF_ICON
from win32gui import NIF_INFO
from win32gui import NIF_MESSAGE
from win32gui import NIF_TIP
from win32gui import NIM_ADD
from win32gui import NIM_DELETE
from win32gui import NIM_MODIFY
from win32gui import RegisterClass
from win32gui import UnregisterClass
from win32gui import Shell_NotifyIcon
from win32gui import UpdateWindow
from win32gui import WNDCLASS
import time


# Callback de evento da janela
def on_proc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
    print(f'Recebido evento de janela, mensagem: {msg}')
    if msg == WM_DESTROY:
        nid = (hwnd, 0)
        # Destruir a notificação quando a janela for destruída
        Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, nid)
        PostQuitMessage(0)

    return None

# Criar janela à qual a notificação pertence (0x0)
wc = WNDCLASS()
hinst = wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(None)
wc.lpszClassName = str("PythonTaskbar")  # must be a string
wc.lpfnWndProc = on_proc

classAtom = RegisterClass(wc)
style = WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_SYSMENU
hwnd = CreateWindow(classAtom, "Taskbar", style,
                         0, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                         CW_USEDEFAULT,
                         0, 0, hinst, None)
UpdateWindow(hwnd)

# Criar a notificação
flags = NIF_ICON | NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_TIP
nid = (hwnd, 0, flags, WM_USER + 20, None, "Tooltip")
Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, nid)

# Mostrar a notificação
Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, (hwnd, 0, NIF_INFO,
                              WM_USER + 20,
                              None, "Balloon Tooltip", "Hello, SO PT", 200, "Título"))

# Esperar 3 segundos e destruir a janela
time.sleep(3)
DestroyWindow(hwnd)
UnregisterClass(wc.lpszClassName, None)
```

Quando a janela recebe uma mensagem de evento, como a de janela destruída, o callback `on_proc` é chamado e exibe o código da mensagem recebida. O que eu gostaria que acontecesse é que ao clicar ou interagir com a notificação, esse callback recebesse a mensagem de interação, já que a janela está ligada à notificação.

A documentação da [API oficial do Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-_notifyicondataa#members) parece indicar que de fato, a janela associada à notificação deveria receber seus eventos:

> Type: HWND
>
> A handle to the window that receives notifications associated with an icon in the notification area.

Infelizmente, a saída do programa mostra que só as mensagens da própria janela, e não da notificação, estão chegando:

```
Recebido evento de janela, mensagem: 144
Recebido evento de janela, mensagem: 2
Recebido evento de janela, mensagem: 130
```

Aqui, o código 2 avisa do evento `WM_DESTROY`, o 130 do `WM_NCDESTROY` e o 144 não sei, mas acontece mesmo quando a notificação não é criada, então não parece ter relação com ela.

Como faço pra receber os eventos relacionados à notificação?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A API do win32 GUI é controlada através de mensagens, que são enviadas para uma fila de mensagens do processo e ficam aguardando lá até serem processadas.

Para um callback ser chamado, você necessita consumir da fila as mensagens que chegam e despachar elas. Isso é consumido através de um message loop. Em C++ o código é mais ou menos o seguinte:

```
while (1) {
    GetMessage(msg);
    DispatchMessage(msg);
}
```

Por que isso é importante? Porque o seu código não tem um message loop. Então, apesar dos eventos de click estarem sendo enfileirados, eles nunca estão sendo consumidos e nunca estão chegando no seu callback. Quando você destrói a janela (`DestroyWindow`), a fila é esvaziada e você perde todos os eventos.

A win32gui tem um método, chamado `PumpMessages`, que faz o loop de mensagens até receber a mensagem `WM_QUIT`. Da documentação:

> PumpMessages: Pumps all messages for the current thread until a WM_QUIT message.

Adicionando o `PumpMessages` antes do `time.sleep` vai fazer com que seu callback receba as mensagens do tooltip. A parte relevante do código modificado ficaria:

```
# Esperar 3 segundos e destruir a janela
win32gui.PumpMessages()
time.sleep(3)
```

Nos meus testes, outros eventos foram impressos pelo callback (1044 é WM_USER + 20):

```
Recebido evento de janela, mensagem: 1044
Recebido evento de janela, mensagem: 799
Recebido evento de janela, mensagem: 1044
```

Comment: Perfeito! O `lparam` da mensagem `1044` é `1028` se a notificação expira sem clique, e `1029` se expira por causa do clique. Muito obrigado!